# Powershell multithreading winforms application

Tags: multithreading, winforms, git, powershell

In the past year I have taken the task to build a PowerShell application.

It's intended purpose at the time of posting this is only for gathering data.

The main point of inspiration is from Francois-Xavier Cat's "◦LazyWinAdmin Tool (WinForm)".

I have used Sapiens PrimalForm to generate the interface then constructed the required scripts.

The interface is working, the scripts are working.

Where I work the only available version of PowerShell is V2, PS remoting and any Invoke-* is restricted.

The main OS is Windows 7 with rare occasions of Win 8/8.1.

As such you will see that al of my scripts use the WMI objects.

Some of my colleagues still have Net Framework 3.5, that must be taken into consideration as some interface elements might interfere.

The main issue that has consumed many hours in the past months is the freezing GUI issue.

Anyone that has tried to make any kind of GUI with PowerShell has encountered this issue.

I have, at this moment, read/bookmarked over 100 forums/webpages/threads for PowerShell multithreading.

I have tested that the RunSpace Pool method, it seems to be the fastest for what I require.

Given the fact that on most of the forums this method is regarded as borderline .NET development I have hit a major wall.

I am, for the life of me, unable to make the interface, threading function and script work together; to make the interface run on a thread and the scripts on a separate thread.

I am posting below the full code for my application.
Please advise if there is a way to overcome the scripts from running on a separate thread.

Since the whole code exceeds the maximum body I must add the app from my Git page:

https://github.com/GeorgeChe/PowershellApp.git

I have thought of dot sourcing the separate scripts and create a sort of modular application, generated more errors than fixed.
I have also included the threading function on the Git page.

Answer (score 0):

To Solve the Freezing GUI Issue, the best IMO is to use Background Jobs to collect the WMI data, this way the form is free and not waiting for the WMI Data to end collecting,

Then you can Use the Timer Control, that will check in the background if the WMI collect is finished, and if so, Update the Form.

Check this link for more information.

https://www.sapien.com/blog/2012/05/16/powershell-studio-creating-responsive-forms/